# Javascript IndexOf not working on forms array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

How come the following happens in the console? or am i misusing the indexOf?

```
document.forms:

[
<form id=​"form-0" name=​"form-0">​…​</form>​
, 
<form id=​"form-1" name=​"form-1">​…​</form>​
, 
<form id=​"form-2" name=​"form-2">​…​</form>​
]

document.forms.indexOf["form-0"]:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'form-0' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Document.forms is a collection. If you want the number of a form - as indicated in your comments -, the question remains: at which moment do you want that number? Anyway, you could create an array of forms:

```
var allforms = document.getElementsByTagName('form'), 
    formsArray = [];
for (var i=0;i<allforms.length;i++){
   if (allforms[i].id.match(/\d+$/)){
       var indexval = parseInt(allforms[i].id.replace(/(.+)(\d+)$/,'$2'),10);
       formsArray[indexval] = allforms[i];
   }
}
```

Now you have an Array containing references to all forms, and for each form an index value that reflects the form number you gave it via it's id. So: `formsArray[0]` contains a reference to `forms['form-0']`, `formsArray[1]` to `forms['form-1']` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You've used the wrong syntax... indexOf is a method, so it should use parenthesis, not brackets.

```
someString.indexOf("form-0")
```

With an object, you can simply request the object using brackets:

```
document.forms["form-0"]
```

Comment: Oh %$^&.. i should delete this question.. :) but while i'm at is there a way to get the number of the form?

Comment: What number? The index in the forms set? You can always loop over the forms.length and then see if the forms[j] iteration is the form you want.

Answer (score 1):

`document.forms` is an [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection).  It is not an array.  As such, it does not have an `indexOf` method.

You can convert it using `Array.prototype.slice.call`:

```
var formsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.forms);
```

Note, however, that `indexOf` is not universally supported.  I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, however, so it may well not be the necessary approach anyway.

Comment: Thanx. actually i'm only trying to get the form's number, how can i do that? extract the number from document.forms[1]

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the element by its ID, just use the ID directly.

```
document.forms['form-0'];
```

If you want its index, it would seem that you already have it in the ID. Just remove the `"form-"` part.

```
var index = 'form-0'.replace('form-','');
```

Or if you have the element, do the same via its ID property:

```
var myform = document.forms['form-0'];
var index = myform.id.replace('form-','')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the elements of a form using javascript, then you have to use this:  document.myform.elements[i], where i is the position of the element. You may refer this [Javascript Form Objects - Properties and Methods tutorial](http://www.w3resource.com/javascript/client-object-property-method/form.php). indexof is a method of javascript string object.